# How to apply a "Custom" Cell Format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

As shown in the screenshot I have selected/created a Custom cell format for the entire `A` column:

[image]

**Note**: the data is actually **`8/17`** and excel is already making a date formatting on it (as seen by the auto converted value of `8/17/2022  12:00:00 AM`). (So there is no need to first format it to a Date).

[image]

However upon hitting `OK` the cell(s) in `A` remain unchanged.  Why was the `Custom` cell format not applied?

Note that when I go to repeat this process Excel *has* remembered that a `Custom` format were selected.

[image]

But then why is the data not conforming to the selected format?

Comment: @ScottCraner  The actual data is `8/17`   so excel already knows it is a date. I will update the question

Comment: Not necessarily: it could be text that looks like a date. Additionally, `8/17` does not include a year...

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I did mention that i had input only 8/17.  The year and time were added automatically. The only way that happens is if excel recognizes it as a date and intelligently adds the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[$-x-sysdate]` in your format string will output the date as your system long date format, no matter the string afterwards. Specify some other culture, or omit it entirely.

Comment: oh ok i'll try that. yes I removed that prefix and simply made `m/d` and works